# Oracle local timezone

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I'm using this expression to convert a date at UTC to its US/Eastern time equivalent:

```
CAST((FROM_TZ(CAST(date_field AS TIMESTAMP),'+00:00') AT TIME ZONE 'US/Eastern') AS DATE) DATE_FIELD_ET
```

I was hoping to use a more generic expression to cast the value to the local time:

```
CAST((FROM_TZ(CAST(note_time AS TIMESTAMP),'+00:00') AT LOCAL TIME ZONE) AS DATE) DATE_FIELD_LOCAL
```

But this syntax doesn't work.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`DBTIMEZONE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions041.htm).

```
CAST((FROM_TZ(CAST(date_field AS TIMESTAMP),'+00:00') AT TIME ZONE DBTIMEZONE) AS DATE) DATE_FIELD_ET
```

Comment: I assume that this will automatically adjust for daylight savings.  Am I correct?

Comment: Are you asking: if the timezone the database is in respects daylight savings, will the code still work? (Just clarifying.)

Comment: Yes, that is what I am asking.

Comment: `DBTIMEZONE` will return whatever timezone the database server is in. This generally won't change with daylight savings as this is considered a bad practice ([see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532729/daylight-saving-time-and-timezone-best-practices)).